# How to construct the union of indexed sets

Tags: python, pyomo

I have a simple problem but I cannot find a simple solution: I have

```
model.H = pym.RangeSet(1,model.h)
model.R = pym.Set(model.H)
```

then I assign values to `R[i]`

Now I would like to define a new set that is the union of all the `R[i]`

I tried a simple for loop but I received a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `union()` method on the first `R` Set to combine it with the others:

```py
>>> from pyomo.environ import *
>>> m = ConcreteModel()
>>> m.H = RangeSet(3)
>>> m.R = Set(m.H, initialize={1:[1,2,3], 2:[10,20], 3:[100,200]})
>>> m.pprint()
1 Set Declarations
    R : Size=3, Index=H, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
          1 :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
          2 :     1 :    Any :    2 : {10, 20}
          3 :     1 :    Any :    2 : {100, 200}

1 RangeSet Declarations
    H : Dimen=1, Size=3, Bounds=(1, 3)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :   [1:3]

2 Declarations: H R
>>> Rs = tuple(m.R.values())
>>> m.ALL_R = Rs[0].union(*Rs[1:])
>>> m.pprint()
3 Set Declarations
    ALL_R : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain               : Size : Members
        None :     1 : ALL_R_index_0 | R[3] :    7 : {1, 2, 3, 10, 20, 100, 200}
    ALL_R_index_0 : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain      : Size : Members
        None :     1 : R[1] | R[2] :    5 : {1, 2, 3, 10, 20}
    R : Size=3, Index=H, Ordered=Insertion
        Key : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
          1 :     1 :    Any :    3 : {1, 2, 3}
          2 :     1 :    Any :    2 : {10, 20}
          3 :     1 :    Any :    2 : {100, 200}

1 RangeSet Declarations
    H : Dimen=1, Size=3, Bounds=(1, 3)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :   [1:3]

4 Declarations: H R ALL_R_index_0 ALL_R
```

Note that Under the hood, Pyomo's `SetUnion` class is only the union of 2 Sets, so in this case, it is automatically generating `SetUnion(SetUnion(m.R[1], m.R[2]), m.R[3])` (explaining the somewhat strange domain reported for `ALL_R`).